# How to find a static String in a Interface

Tags: java, string, interface, static

I have the folowing interface;

```
public static interface Attributes
{
        public final static String InterestDeterminationDate = "InterestDeterminationDate";
        public final static String CreditType = "CreditType";
        public final static String NumberInternal = "NumberInternal";
        public final static String InterestRate = "InterestRate";
        public final static String RemainingDebtAmount = "RemainingDebtAmount";
        public final static String ConsumerPart = "ConsumerPart";
        public final static String TechnicalProductName = "TechnicalProductName";
        public final static String TermOfDuration = "TermOfDuration";
        public final static String PeriodInterestTaxReduction = "PeriodInterestTaxReduction";
        public final static String OriginMark = "OriginMark";
        public final static String Currency = "Currency";
        public final static String PenaltyRuleId = "PenaltyRuleId";
        public final static String InstallmentCalculationMethod = "InstallmentCalculationMethod";
        public final static String InterestRenewalDate = "InterestRenewalDate";
        public final static String TechnicalProductDescription = "TechnicalProductDescription";
        public final static String TechnicalProductDate = "TechnicalProductDate";
        public final static String CollectionIntervalPeriod = "CollectionIntervalPeriod";
        public final static String Enddate = "Enddate";
}
```

I need to check is a given string is a part of this Attributes Interface.

How can i check this?

Regards,
bas Hendriks

Comment: What do you mean with "string is a part of this Attributes Interface"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't make it clear whether you're trying to find out if the query string is the property name or value. If you're trying to find out if it's a value, the following will work:

```
public static boolean hasValue(String value) throws IllegalAccessException {
    for(Field field : Attributes.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if(((String)field.get(Attributes.class)).equals(value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I would advise following [Colin's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558830/how-to-find-a-static-string-in-a-interface/3558906#3558906) of using an `Enum`, it will be easier for you to work with in the future.

Comment: I agree with Colin. His suggestion is better, but i'm limited to java 1.4 (and cannot alter the interface)

Answer (score 5):

If you really want todo this, then you should use reflection and go through all the values in Attributes.

A better way to do this would be the use of enums :

```
public enum Attributes{
    InterestDeterminationDate,
    CreditType,
    NumberInternal,
    InterestRate,
    RemainingDebtAmount,
    ConsumerPart,
    TechnicalProductName,
    TermOfDuration,
    PeriodInterestTaxReduction,
    OriginMark,
    Currency,
    PenaltyRuleId,
    InstallmentCalculationMethod,
    InterestRenewalDate,
    TechnicalProductDescription,
    TechnicalProductDate,
    CollectionIntervalPeriod,
    Enddate;
}
```

and the `Attributes.valueOf(yourVariable);` would check this for you.

Beware with enum, the `valueOf()` method will throw a `IllegalArgumentException` if `yourVariable` isn't in `Attributes`. Plus you `yourVariable` isn't `null` or you will have to handle a `NullPointerException`

Comment: @BasHendriks: Also, if you want to stick with Strings (and reflection), it is better to put them in a final class rather than an interface. Interfaces are not meant for this purpose.

Comment: I agree that enums should be the right way to do this, but i have two limitations: I cannot change the interface. I have to use this. And i'm limited to java 1.4.......

Comment: Then look at other solutions. But you should specify your limitation when you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reflection API, and the "getFields()" method of the [Class class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Then you check the field name with the "getName()" method of the [Field class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html).

Here is the [Oracle official tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can build a set using reflection and test against that set:

```
Class<Attributes> attr = Attributes.class;
Field[] fields = attr.getDeclaredFields();
final Set<String> fieldsInAttributes = new HashSet<String>();
for (Field field : fields) {
    fieldsInAttributes.add(field.getName());
}

System.out.println(fieldsInAttributes.contains("PenaltyRuleId"));
```

Comment: This will search the field names for the target string. I think he wants the field values, rather than the names.

Comment: They're the same in the example but, yeah, you're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getFieldName(String fieldValue) throws Exception {
  for (Field field : Attributes.class.getFields()) 
    if (fieldValue.equals(field.get(null)))
      return field.getName();
  return null;
}
```